# What is an XMPP Domain Name?

Tags: dns, xmpp

I'm having trouble setting up Openfire. The default XMPP Domain Name on the Openfire setup is displaying my computer name, thereby whenever i test through Spark it's not working.

I've tried a domain that i own and a error appeared in the openfire console to add two srv records. After adding the records I'm still unsuccessful in connecting to my openfire server..

So my question is, is XMPP Domain Name just a normal domain? Or do i need to edit some  A / SRV records?

Really stuck on getting Openfire up and running, all help will be gratefully appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XMPP addresses, also known as JIDs (Jabber Identifiers) have the form

```
<localpart>@<domainpart>/<resourcepart>
```

where `localpart` and `resourcepart` are optional. According to [RFC 7622 § 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7622#section-3.2) the domainpart can be either a fully qualified domain, an IPv4 or v6 address or an unqualified hostname.

> The domainpart for every XMPP service MUST be a fully qualified domain
> name (FQDN), an IPv4 address, an IPv6 address, or an unqualified
> hostname (i.e., a text label that is resolvable on a local network).

So a **XMPP domain** is either

- a FQDN like "example.org" (a DNS name)
- an IPv4 address
- an IPv6 address
- an unqualified hostname like "localhost" or "foo"

**XMPP servers** like Openfire need to know which domain(s) they server. So you need to configure their XMPP domain(s), which is basically the value of the  of the JIDs they are responsible for.

**XMPP clients**, after they have been configured with the user's JID and password, discover the IP addresses and port numbers which serve the XMPP domain of their JID, via a lookup of the matching `_xmpp-client` SRV resource record (with an optional fallback to an A/AAAA lookup on the XMPP domain name).